# Adjusting y-Axis in Core Plot when x-Axis changes

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a chart with only a certain range of the plot showing. When I scroll to the right a differtent range is shown. Works fine. But how do I adjust the y-Axis to the range of the points currently shown? I dont want the range of all points of a plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only built-in method sets both the x- and y-ranges to fit all of the plot data. You can set the `yRange` to anything you want. Either search your dataset for all of the visible points and compute the range from those points, or use some knowledge about the data (e.g., its always increasing) if you have any to make the range calculation easier.